# Mostrar e esconder apenas o elemento desejado

Tags: react

Esto fazendo um tipo de lista em que quando clico em qualquer lugar do item desejado é para aparecer informações apenas daquele que cliquei, porém do jeito que fiz está mudando a variável "open" globalmente, então as informações vai aparecer em todos da lista mesmo que eu clique apenas em um item.

O correto então era eu enviar o id do item como parâmetro para a função que vai mostrar e esconder as informações, porém não faço ideia de como implementar isso para fazer com que uma função retorne a variável open como true ou false apenas para um elemento da lista.

```
function Home() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    if (open == false) { var classeBar = 'collapsed' }
    else {var inBar = 'in' }
return (
    <div>
        <ContentHeader title='Meus Projetos' />
        <Content>
            <div className={classeBar}>
            <div className='list-proj ponteiro' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id1" aria-expanded={open} aria-controls='id1'>
                <div className='col-md-9 col-xs-12'>
                    <div className='alinhar'>
                        <h2 className='title-proj'>Mouse com pendrive</h2>
                        <div className='lider-e-orien'>
                            <span>Lider: Chris <br />
                                Orientador: Ander</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <span className='separador'></span>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi maiores culpa consequuntur explicabo consectetur repellendus optio inventore laudantium? Quas totam ullam a perspiciatis ea dolores doloribus iste exercitationem, neque eligendi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='status-proj col-md-3'>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Status</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span className='status-color'>Em aprovação</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='id1' className={`collapse ${inBar}`} aria-expanded={open}>
                <div className='col-md-6'>
                <h3>oi</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-6'>
                <h3>oi</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </Content>
    </div>
)
```

}

No código acima há apenas um item mas é para encurtar para que vocês possam analisar, depois vou fazer a conexão com o back e chamar a função map para percorrer todo o array da query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine que cada mudança do estado demonstra a forma como seu componente inteiro vai ser exibido.
Se seguir esse raciocínio chegará a seguinte conclusão:

"Se eu tenho um componente (Home) que tem uma lista de itens (considere o tamanho da lista como **x**) e para cada item eu posso exibir um collapse mostrando seus detalhes, meu componente deverá ter uma quantidade de estado no mínimo do tamanho de **x**."

Em outras palavras, cada mudança no que é visto em *Home* representa um estado do componente. Se você tem uma lista de item e cada item pode mudar sua aparencia, significa que o componente *Home* deve ter estados suficientes para todos os itens.

Isso é totalmente enviável.

No entanto, você poderá separar um pouco mais seu código, de forma que cada item fique dentro de seu próprio componente.
Assim, o componente Home não precisa se preocupar com os estados de collapse de cada item. Na verdade, cada item precisa se preocupar com seu próprio estado de collapse. Sacas?

Deixa eu exemplificar pra você.

```
function Home(){
  return (lista.map(item => <Item item={item}/>));
}
function Item({item}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); //começa como não aberto
  return <div>{item.nome}{open && <span>mais informações do item {item.nome} }</span></div>
}
```

Analise bem esse código.
Cada item tem agora a responsabilidade de dar seu proprio collapse e você isenta o componente Home de controlar o estado de todo mundo.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida comenta esse post.